# fopen('my directory') failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-routing

I using storeAs to store an uploaded file. Everytime I test it, I always get that message (see the title). How to fix it?

Comment: You need add some code that shows how are you storing a file?

Answer (score -1):

Mmm, you need to provide more information to really get helped :-)
Please provide at least the upload part of your code and the complete error message.

The first thing I would check (if you're working on linux) is the upload folder permissions. It's a common source of errors.